# Best Practice for DB Migrations that Affect Many Tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-design

Say you have a database of 50 tables.  You are making a change to the wording of one of the columns that by relationship affects 20 of those tables.  How would you set up this migration? I see at least three possibilities

1. a separate migration for a change on every table
2. a single migration for all of them
3. changing the initial declaration of the creation of the tables.

I'm quite confident 3 is the worst approach because now everyone cannot simply migrate up but would have to rebuild the entire schema.  But I'm stuck between 1 and 2. 2 is probably the best approach because you are creating one migration for one change that just so happens to affect a lot of tables. This is what I'm leaning towards.  On the other hand, it feels very messy.

Any resources on this would be appreciated as well. Thanks

Comment: Assuming that *change to the wording of one of the columns* means that you want to rename a column, the *dbms* probably doesn't require changes to referencing tables.

Answer (score 0):

It makes more sense to go for option 2.

Say you take option one and do x separate migrations. You'll end up with x migrations that by themselves will mess up with your database's integrity, so you'll have to run them all together (or rollback them all together if you want to undo the changes). So if all your changes need to be made together, then it makes sense to put them together in the same file

Comment: Yeah, I decided to go with that approach.  Thanks